# how to publish npm and maven in same maven reactor build using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, maven-2, npm, build-process, nexus

Is there a way to publish to both an npm and a maven repository in a Jenkins job using one Maven2 reactor build pom file? The reactor build pom file contains two modules, one is a standard jar module and the other is a pom module that uses the exec plugin to call npm script targets that build the javascript project. Jenkins is configured to publish the maven dependencies to a corporate nexus server when build succeeds.

Project Layout:

```
project/
  pom.xml
  npm-module/
    pom.xml
  mvn-module/
    pom.xml
```

This works great for the mvn-module and the npm-module builds. But now the trick is publishing the npm-module. Jenkins seems to only allow one publish to nexus post-build task.

Is there a way to do this? Can anyone explain how to set up Jenkins and a reactor build pom file that publishes both npm and maven modules to nexus?

Comment: UPDATE: I replaced the exec plugin with https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin, which makes npm, gulp, and grunt first class citizens in maven but I still do not know how to get the "jenkins publish to maven repositories" post build step to also publish npm artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

I have an answer but would love to hear other ideas.

**Jenkins Setup**

- create pre step "execute shell" to set npm _auth and email fields

  ```
  npm config set _auth authhashstring  
  npm config set email some@email.com
  ```
- add deploy to the maven "goals and options"

  ```
  clean deploy -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dfullclean=true
  ```
- add "settings file from filesystem"

  ```
  config/maven-settings.xml
  ```

Note: use the deploy goal instead of the jenkins "deploy artifacts to maven" post step because it does not use maven so your npm goals won't get called.

**`pom.xml` Setup**

In npm-module/pom.xml use frontend-maven-plugin and add executions to install node/npm and for npm publish. Make sure the publish is attached to the deploy phase. The [instructions](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) were good enough. Or you can use the exec plugin to execute the `npm publish` command on the deploy phase.

In mvn-module/pom.xml add the distributionManagement/snapshotRepository for your snapshots repo location.

**maven `settings.xml` Setup**

We put the maven settings.xml with the username and password in the project in a config directory, like this, mvn-module/config/maven-settings.xml. This is not ideal but we can replace the username and password w/ properties that can be set from maven/jenkins, I think. Jenkins will be configured to read this file from this location.

**`package.json` Setup**

In npm-module/package.json add the publishConfig/registry entry

```
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": "url/nexus/content/repositories/npm-snapshots/"
}
```

**Nexus Setup**

The npm-snapshots hosted repository is set to allow redeploy. This is probably not a great idea but may be good enough for ongoing new development (not for releases obviously) and I was just trying to get the stack working. I will now need to work out the kinks.

So with that caveat aside, now the jenkins build will publish both java and node modules to their respective repositories from one Jenkins job using a top-level multi-module reactor pom.